# Make PhpStorm watch (specific) file and upload upon change

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp, phpstorm

I'm looking for a way for PhpStorm to watch a file - so that every time it changes, it should sync that file to the remote server. And the 'Upload external changes'-option (with the 'On explicit save action') is *not* working for me. It's close - but no cigar. It makes me save the css-file twice - and only after the second time I save the scss-file, then it uploads the gulp-compiled-style.css-file, as I would like it to do after the first 'save'. I know it's an itty-bitty thing - but for something that I easily do 200-400 times per day, I would like it to run as smooth as possible. It's both the time I spend saving the file twice - but it's also the doubt in my mind, every time something doesn't act like I want it to - then I always have to check first, if the file is uploaded properly.

I'm working with Wordpress and I have a 5-8 SCSS-files, that are being compiled using gulp. The gulp-procedures are quite comprehensive (autoprefixer, merge-media-queries, minifycss, etc., etc.), so it takes a couple of miliseconds for the file to be compiled. I assume that it's that compile-time that makes PhpStorm 'miss' that the style.css has changed - and therefore don't upload it on the first 'save'. Because sometimes everything is uploaded after the first 'save' - but it's only every 8th time (or so).

Extra fun fact (that may indicate where the body is burried): If i run the `gulp watch` from a terminal in the background, then I have to save the file, wait for at least 2-4 seconds and then save again, before the gulp-compiled-style.css-file is uploaded. If I press 'save', 'save', 'save', 'save' - with less than those 2-4 seconds pause, but with only 1 seconds pause, then PhpStorm never sync's the gulp-compiled-style.css-file. 
   If I run the `gulp watch` from PhpStorm's Gulp-integration (not the terminal, but the Gulp-prompt), then I can save twice in a row with only .5 second pause between (as soon as the progress bar in the bottom disappears) - and then it uploads (every time, - consistently).

It's only the upload of the gulp-compiled-style.css-file that is the problem. Everything else is working perfectly.

Here's what I have tried:

**Attempt1) I've previously used Atom, where the FTP-configuration was established using a plugin with a .ftpconfig-file. In that file, there was a `'watch: []'`-parameter, where I could specify a file to 'watch'. That worked wonders!! I've tried finding a plugin that did something of the sort - but couldn't find it.

**Attempt2) I read one of the [support-pages](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206339719-PHPStorm-doesn-t-upload-CSS-files-when-using-file-watcher-for-SCSS-using-Compass), concerning the same. It seems like that if the SCSS-files are compiled using PhpStorm, then it knows to upload the style.css-file (after it has been compiled). I can't setup my gulp-file using PhpStorms' SCSS-compilation (since it compiles it and then pipes the content through multiple procedures. And if I change projects and have to set that up every time, then that would be a pain to maintain.

**Attempt3) I thought about making a macro or something. And then seeing if I could remap `CMD-s` to 'save-current-file-and-execute-the-macro'. But then if I don't edit the scss-file (but just some php-file), then it would still upload the style.css-file. It's by no means a pretty solution, - but it just shows how far out in the ropes I've been, to find a solution to automate this.

**Attempt4) I thought about building it into the gulp-file, that it has to upload the style.css-file after compiling the style.css-file. I thought about getting the host and the username from the `.idea`-folder - and getting the password from the keychain and then establishing the sftp-connection that way. But it quickly became extensive to do this, so I hoped that there was an easier/better way.

**Addition1**

LazyOne asked, what I had tried with the File Watchers, so here goes. I tried making PhpStorm compile the Scss-file (so PhpStorm basically did what Gulp does for me today). 
So that was a SCSS-filewatcher (file type), the scope was the SCSS-files in my project, pointed the 'Program' to my ruby-installed scss-file, etc., etc., etc.

However... I realized that it was difficult to get PhpStorm to do the same thing to the Scss-files as the Gulp-file does.

The Gulp-file that I'm using is supplied with each project (as a default) - and we're several webdesigners working on the same projects. So if I suddenly do something other that use that Gulp-file, then I'm pretty sure that I will have to be able to produce the exact same result, - otherwise I'm pretty sure that my colleagues will skin me alive. But I made it as far as to have this as my Arguments, before I gave up (I still need to do several things in this line, before it does what my Gulp-file does):

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:../../style.css --style compressed --sourcemap=none
```

... However... When doing that, then I could conclude that the style.css-file **was** uploaded on every save (score!). Which means that if I can just setup some kind of File Watcher, then hopefully PhpStorm will watch that file and therefore upload it after Gulp has compiled the style.css.

So I tried to make a File Watcher, that watches the style.css-file - but I didn't know what to put as my 'Program'. Since basically I want PhpStorm to poke the style.css-file three times with a stick - and thereafter realize that the file has changed and upload it to the server. Is that possible to do automatically?

Comment: IF you are compiling your stuff outside of the IDE (`gulp watch` and alike) ... then the best I could offer is to 1) Try to actually implement this as File Watcher. if you already tried that -- show what you have tried. If you check my comments in that forum thread -- it should work 2) Hit `File | Synchronize` manually (this action checks all local project files looking for possible changes that were done outside of the IDE). Once such change is found, the "Upload external changes" should jump in.

Comment: Thanks for you input @LazyOne. I've made an 'addition'-section explaining my attempt at the File Watcher.

Comment: Well ... 1) You can have multiple file watchers processing the same file (will be run one after another) or you just batch them (via custom intermediate script .. or a gulp task) 2) you can create dedicated gulp task that will do such compile/whatever (so you keep all the logic inside) and call it in File Watcher. In both cases (as I have stated in that forum thread) the key is to point `Path to refresh` field to a target generated file -- it's the one that IDE will be checking for changes after file watcher is done.

Comment: Hey again. Thanks for your response. So what you're saying is: 1) I could make a bunch of File Watchers, and hope that one of them run after the file has changed and therefore notice the changed file and sync it? If I've understood that correctly - can you give an example of a File Watcher-setup that does that? ... Or 2) And can call a File Watcher from my Gulp-file? ... That sounds like the better solution. How do I do that? And even if I do that - I'm still unsure on how to setup the File Watcher. Which 'Program' to use, for example.

Comment: No for both. In #1 I meant -- if you need to run few different things on one/the same file (e.g. first "scss into css"; then "prefixer"; then "minification") then you can setup 3 file watchers and they will run one after another. But that's not ideal.

Comment: Therefore I suggest #2 .. where I mean -- execute dedicated gulp task as a File Watcher. This means: create separate gulp task (or whatever you have got there already) that will do such "compile this file" job. Then -- use it in File Watcher -- execute that gulp task from there. Program -- path to your gulp executable; params -- whatever params needed to execute this gulp task in command line.

Comment: I'll be honest -- I do not have any working examples around (I have not used this myself -- I'm using only "basic" file watchers -- compile SCSS/LESS using `node-sass` or `lessc` -- it's enough for what I'm doing here. But I will try to find one. In meantime -- have you tried Gulp integration in PhpStorm https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/11/gulp-in-webstorm-9/ (it has dedicated tool window)? If you run such "gulp watch" task from there it should be picking up such file modifications (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14873 or https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28567)

Comment: I have tried with the Gulp-integration. I also tried to describe that in the post - but was lacking that word. I've added the proper words now. There's an improvement, when I use PhpStorms Gulp-integration (it uploads consistently after the 2nd save). But it's still after the 2nd save.

However... You've gotten me onto something! If I run the Gulp Watch-task from the File Watcher, then it watches the style.css-file and uploads it on every save of the scss-files! Yay!! I'm still getting some errors in the output window (telling me to run npm install gulp). I'll sort that out and post answer.

Comment: I'm posting my answer now. How can I give you the points, @LazyOne ? You led me to the answer and deserve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Here's how it's done!

The important part is that PhpStorm watches the style.css-file. It will do that, if you point a File Watcher to look at the file. Now, at first I tried running the Gulp-file with a File Watcher. Then I tried compiling the scss-files with the File Watcher. But that is not necessary. The important part is the 'Output paths to refresh' (as @LazyOne pointed out in the comments). So the best solution I've come to, is to make a bash-script that does nothing. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep .01
```

I've called that 'donothing'. I don't have to do the `sleep .01` for it to work, - but it doesn't stop it from working (based on the 20 upload tests I've done). And in my mind, it's better if there's a short delay, after the scss-files are saved (so the gulp-integration in PhpStorm have time to finish compiling the style.css-file).

Here's the setup of my File Watcher: 
[image]

The scope is a custom-made one, and I've set it to this:

```
file[PROJECTNAME]:wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/assets/sass/*
```

But I assume the scope could just be the entire project, since it's just looking for when SCSS-files change in that scope, before the 'Program' is executed (if I've understood this whole File Watcher thingy properly).

And I'm working on a project, where the SCSS-files are at

```
/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/assets/sass/STYLEDIRNAME/
```

And in this case, then the 'Output paths to refresh' should be set to something along these lines:

```
$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$/../../style.css
```

or

```
$ProjectFileDir$/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/style.css
```

And if you unfold 'Other options', then you have to set `Working directory` to be the root of the project, for it to work:

```
/Users/USERNAME/dropbox/foo/bar/
```

A downfall for this solution is, if PhpStorm are faster than the Gulp-task, - since it would then upload the style.css-file before the Gulp-task has finished compiling it (and therefore uploading the old or an incomplete file). That didn't happen during my 20 brief tests. But if it happens, then I would set a higher delay in the 'donothing'-file and see if that solves it.

**Addition 1**

I just experienced, that it wasn't working - that it didn't upload `style.css` upon every compilation/save (but I could swear that the setup was correct). So I restarted PhpStorm and then it worked. I tried restarting the `gulp watch`-process first, - but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another, much simpler solution is to set the File Watchers scope for SCSS files to "**All Changed Files**".

[This is what my File Watcher setup looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9jKH.jpg).

It compiles the .scss file, copies the minified .css into another folder, and then automatically uploads both files to the server if you have "Auto upload" enabled.

*(You might note that I'm not using the SCSS compiler but the PHP-based [PSCSS](https://github.com/leafo/scssphp), which is about 70% faster and can be [installed](https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/) via `composer global require scssphp/scssphp`).*